# linq grouping result takes a long time

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have the following method that does some grouping

```
private List<CatalogVehicle> GroupResult(IEnumerable<VehicleAndQuote> vehiclesAndQuotes)
    {
        var vehicles = vehiclesAndQuotes
            .GroupBy(vehicleAndQuote =>
                new
                {
                    vehicleAndQuote.Vehicle.VehicleMakeName,
                    vehicleAndQuote.Vehicle.VehicleModelTypeName,
                    vehicleAndQuote.Vehicle.VehicleEdition
                })
            .Select(a => new
            {
                vehicle = _mapper.Map<VehicleAndQuote, CatalogVehicle>(a.First()),
                plans = GetLeasingpPlansGroupedByYearlyMileages(a.ToList()) //<== this one is taking ages
            })
            .Select(a =>
            {
                a.vehicle.LeasingPlans = a.plans;
                return a.vehicle;
            });

        return vehicles.ToList();
    }
```

and the method that is calling within;

```
    private List<LeasingPlan> GetLeasingpPlansGroupedByYearlyMileages(IEnumerable<VehicleAndQuote> vehicleAndQuotes)
    {
        return vehicleAndQuotes.GroupBy(quote => quote.Quote.YearlyMileage)
            .Select(group => _mapper.Map<List<VehicleAndQuote>, LeasingPlan>(group.ToList()))
            .ToList();
    }
```

the last method takes quite a long time. 
the `IEnumerable<VehicleAndQuote> vehiclesAndQuotes` is about 30.000 records. 
Is there any performance gainer that I am not seeing?

Comment: What if you don't call `ToList()` at the end of the second method ? Do you *really* need list, or it is enough to return `IEnumerable<T>` ?. Calling `ToList()` is a creation of a whole new collection, and that is clear performance hit, especially when the count of elements starts to become big enough.

Comment: You have, actually, calls to `ToList()` all over the places inside the queries. Remove them too.

Comment: Try to execute the more on the database side. Those ToList are doing o lot of harm. In addition, try to delay the automapper to its own select at the end after the SQL translatable part

Comment: @Tigran let me try it..

Comment: The group already implements `IEnumerable<VehicleAndQuote>`, therefore you can just call `plans = GetLeasingpPlansGroupedByYearlyMileages(a)`. Automapper accepts `IEnumerable<T>` as source as well.

Comment: @Tigran i need the list later, so the execution will take place there; hence, it is taking again ages...

Comment: Maybe you could simplify calculating the group key? Try changing it into a concatenated string instead of anonymours object. GroupBy tries to calculate hash from that, make it easier.

Comment: @RoelantM: at least create it *only* where it's needed. After use some profiler to get insights about performance bottlenecks. 30K is not a big number, by far, to be considered slow to process, especially on modern processors.

Comment: @RoelantM: if there is DB access, somehow is happenning, verify that it's not a bottleneck.

Comment: @RoelantM May be it's your mapping which is consuming too much resources, you might want to post your CreateMap statement. Especially a mapping between List<VehicleAndQuote> and LeasingPlan.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to translate your query to a version that is more database friendly.

```
var vehicles = vehiclesAndQuotes
    .GroupBy(vehicleAndQuote =>
                new {
                    vehicleAndQuote.Vehicle.VehicleMakeName,
                    vehicleAndQuote.Vehicle.VehicleModelTypeName,
                    vehicleAndQuote.Vehicle.VehicleEdition
                })
            .Select(a => new {
                // DB friendly
                vehicle = a.First(),
                plans = a.GroupBy(quote => quote.Quote.YearlyMileage)
            })
            .AsEnumerable() // May o may not be needed / passing to LINQ to Objects
            .Select(a => {
                var vehicle = _mapper.Map<VehicleAndQuote, CatalogVehicle>(a.vehicle);
                var plans = a.plans.Select(group => _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<VehicleAndQuote>, LeasingPlan>(group));
                vehicle.LeasingPlans = plans;
                return vehicle;
            });

return vehicles.ToList(); // This should be avoided, specially if you are processing a large collection.
```

This way you are doing the double grouping in the database side is possible. Also, I'm not materializing the whole collection until the end.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thnx, but this is not at the database at all... any other thoughts..?

Comment: I didn't expect it to compile, I just copied & edited on the stackoverflow editor ;-)

Comment: @RoelantM if the database is out of the equation, you version of the code is pretty close to the best way to get the data you want. For something better you need to fundamentally change what you are doing.

Comment: Additional ideals: use parralelism to speed up the loading and the grouping, etc, etc

Comment: @RoelantM check the parallel additions.

Comment: Some statements are not terminated by semicolons in the last Select. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the generated query in `SQL Profiler`. Your query is doing a select for each record `(N+1 problem)` in both `vehicle` and `plans`. If you are using `Entity Framework 2.0`, you should know that it runs `GroupBy` locally and fetches all data from the database into memory like `SELECT *` and then groups them in memory. Break your query in multiple queries for each entity. Don't use `LINQ` functions like `First()` in your `Select` LINQ function, because it causes `N+1 SQL Issue`. Upgrade your EF version to 2.1 or upper to avoid `Local GroupBy` problem.

Comment: sorry, I didn't see IEnumerable<VehicleAndQuote>

Comment: np, any thoughts?